# Sort by brand name a-z Woocommerce overrides all other taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

## Update on the issue*

So! I've been working with the code as posted by L7c1f3r below but i just can't seem to get it to work. I have to declare the taxonomy as an orderable variable for the $args somehow but i can't find any helpful posts - i've tried out most of the answers i've found but still - no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Original post

First question on stackoverflow!

I have a wordpress development site where i use the Woocommerce plugin to sell products. I have the brands plugin as well.  Our company revolves a lot around marketing the products around the brand. So i've been looking for a way to override the default sorting options on the woocommerce product archive pages to go Alphabetically by brand name instead of the other standard options.

**Update: Clarifying the supposed function***

Product A belongs to Brand A

Product B belongs to Brand B

Product C belongs to Brand A

The ordering should output the products like this:

Product A, Brand A

Product C, Brand A

Product B, Brand B

..........

After a lot of looking around the web for answers i found the following snippet:

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_with_tax', 10, 2);
function posts_clauses_with_tax( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;


$taxonomies = array('product_brand');

$orderBy['field'] = "product_brand";
$orderBy['direction'] = "ASC";

if(in_array($orderBy['field'], $taxonomies)) {
    $clauses['join'] .= "
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel2 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = rel2.object_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax2 ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
    ";

    $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '".$orderBy['field']."' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "rel2.object_id";
    $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.slug ORDER BY slug ASC) ";
  //  $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $orderBy['direction'] ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    $clauses['orderby'] .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC"; 
    return $clauses;
}

else {
    return $clauses;
}



}
```

The snippet does the job, however - it also removes all **other** taxonomies (posts, images etc) from view and use. See images before and after.

[Before running snippet - Media library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC7yk.jpg)

[Before running snippet - Posts page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFRzi.jpg)

[After running snippet - Media Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npy1I.jpg)

[After running snippet - Posts page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUJ3.jpg)

I **think** that the issue is that the snippet is assuming that all types of taxonomies have a field called "brand" associated to it and that's why it all gets removed when it can't find it in the post taxonomy for example. I've tried to declare the product taxonomy and add it as an dependable variable in the if-statement but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to make this function run only for the taxonomy 'product_brand'? Or, if there's an even better way to do what i'm trying to accomplish i would appreciate the help immensely.